# Starting from hibernate switches off the computer

Tags: hibernate

Since a batch of upates installed a few weeks ago, when the system starts from hibernation, after reading the saved hibernation state, on reaching the point that it switches to graphical mode, the computer powers off. It changes back to text mode and does what looks like a fast, but controlled, Linux shutdown and the computer switches off. When it is started again the system boots normally (i.e. hibernation state lost/ignored.)

I'm at a loss diagnosing this problem. I've looked into system.log, pm-suspend.log, dmesg... without seeing a trace of what happened on the de-hibernation process. I came here looking for advice on how to investigate this. If there is a more appropriate forum, please tell me.

The main suspects on the list of upgraded packages are libdrm, libkms and libc. It also upgraded qt and the kernel, but since the update the problem also happens with the old kernel, so I discarded the kernel as the probable cause.

Suspend to RAM works fine.

I'm on Kubuntu 13.04 AMD64.

Answer (score 1):

After noting that the problem only happens when the hardware power button is pressed (resume from hibernation works fine when the hibernation was started from the command line or the KDE GUI) I discovered that the script /etc/acpi/powerbtn.sh was failing to detect the presence of KDE. In theory, when this script detects the presence of environments that handle the power button press by themselves, it bails out. AFAIK, for KDE it tests for the presence of kpowersave, but it is missing on this system, so the script goes on and switchess off the computer. This happens just after the systems resumes from hibernation, because the script execution was freezed when the machine entered hibernation.

I put an `exit' at the beginning of the script and now everything works fine.